# `ninja` with multiple `build.ninja` files?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, ninja

I would like to launch multiple `ninja` builds simultaneously. Each build is in its own directory and has its own `build.ninja` file.

I could just do the following:

```
cd <build-dir-1>
ninja &
cd <build-dir-2>
ninja &
...
cd <build-dir-last>
ninja
```

....but there are a couple of issues with this:

- The default number of threads used by Ninja probably isn't optimal when launching multiple independent builds simultaneously.
- Output will, I expect, be interleaved in a non-sensible way.

**EDIT** I could also just keep the `ninja` calls in the foreground (which is what I'm currently doing), but then there would be no easy way to estimate what the current progress of the (entire) build is.

So, I would like to do one of the following:

1. merge the `build.ninja` files into one big file that can perform
   both builds in one `ninja` invocation.
2. somehow launch `ninja` with multiple target `build.ninja` scripts.

It doesn't look like that second option is supported by `ninja`, but the first seems like it could be done easily enough using `subninja <build-dir-n>/build.ninja`. Has anyone done something like this before? Are there any hidden pitfalls? Alternatively, I could just perform the builds in sequence (i.e. the above sequence but without the `&`s), but this doesn't feel like the right solution.

#### Use-case

I'm using `CMake`, which generates a separate `build.ninja` file for each build configuration (release and debug). I'm also targeting multiple platforms, so I have multiple compiler, and CMake must be run separately for each platform. So if I want to build release *and* debug code for *all* platforms, I need to run `ninja` multiple times.

Comment: Why don't you simply build sequentially your release and debug version and your multiple platform, each one with the optimal number of threads? `cd <build-dir-1> && ninja && cd <build-dir-2> && ninja && cd [...]`

Comment: @Antonio That's what I'm currently doing, but I was hoping there might be a better way.

Comment: Are you speaking of builds that involve a lot of files? In this case I would struggle to see a benefit. Do you have to trigger all these builds at each file modifications (therefore trigger a build on a few files), or the full set of builds is only seldom necessary?

Comment: Use GNU Parallel to build them all in parallel: `find . -depth 1 -type d -print0 | parallel -0 cd {}'&&' ninja`

Comment: @sakra That's interesting (and I think your comment is how I learned about GNU Parallel, so thank you), but I expect it would interact poorly with Ninja's built-in parallelism smartness.

Comment: @Antonio I've edited the question to mention that one of the primary frustrations with running sequential foreground `ninja` operations is that estimating the build progress becomes impossible.

Comment: Imagine you do a full build, then make a single source change that means each ninja build needs to build, say, three files.  There is no optimal number of threads, since each individual ninja run only can run three simultaneous compiles.  A top-level ninja build could run many more in parallel.  In our case, we have many ninja directories (created by cmake) for combinations of architecture/debug,release/etc.